# Gas issue on remix

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale

I need your help, please. I've been trying to deploy a simple token and crowdsale contract that creates the token on remix, but when I try to deploy the crowdsale contract, it tells me gas exceeds the current block limit. I've tried increasing the gas limit severally, but it's still telling me the same thing. Please what can I do?

Comment: Are you using the Javascript VM as the environment?

Comment: Harry Wright, no I'm not. I'm using injected web with metamask

Comment: What test net are you using? What gas price are you using?

Comment: Harry Wright, im using ropsten, and gas limit is 3000000. I even set it as high as 90000000 when trying to deploy, but it's not working. Still says gas required exceeds limit.

Comment: What is that gas *price* though, they are different things. Maybe you are setting that gas limit too high. You also need to make sure you have the ether to pay for the transaction in your account.

Comment: I have lots of ether in it. I've done everything possible, even others have complained about it too. Please, is there any crowdsale contract I can create that I can send tokens to then people will be able to send ether and get the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed when deploying within truffle or remix that if my contracts don't adhere to their interfaces, they will compile but won't deploy, and will complain about the gas limit. Check that any contracts that implement an interface implement it correctly.